# superfish vertical menu

Tags: jquery-plugins, superfish

Im using jQuery with superfish vertical menu.

My menu is positioned at the bottom of my page so the menu slides up, however, on hover of the menu items the sub items get lost at the bottom of my window. Below is a crude example of whats happening.

```
   menu item 
   menu item 
   menu item
   menu item > sub item
browser bottom--------------------------
               sub item
               sub item
               sub item
```

This is my desired outcome

```
   menu item   sub item
   menu item   sub item
   menu item   sub item
   menu item > sub item
browser bottom--------------------------
```

Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could take a look on this plugins which relocate any submenus which is appearing outside the browser window :

[Supposition Alpha Release](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/supposition-test/menuAtTop.html)